# Sprite Animation flickering in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play sprite animation in unity, it is playing but when ut is playing the animation is flickering

How to solve this issue

Comment: what is a `sprite animation` exactly?

Comment: I have sprite image (png sequence) by which I've created animation, it is playing perfectly but it is flickering

Comment: created with what? Into which video format? Displayed in Unity how?

Comment: Please add a video showing it, including the animation window in Unity

Answer (score 9):

I had a sprite animation on layer 0 placed on top of a background sprite image and got the flickering as well.

Change the sprite "order in layer" property to 1 (and leave your background sprite set to "order in layer" zero.

Flashing went away.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I fixed mine by adjusting the sorting layer. The flickering is caused by overlapping sprite.

Answer (score 1):

So, your post came up in the searches. I was having a similar issue. For me, the animation would play, but there was a couple of bad frames/sprites that would be there as far as 'in' the animation, but they just weren't showing on screen. I could click on the frame image and it would show, but during animation it would disappear, causing the flashes.

But, by having the pop-out animation window open that can play frame by frame, I could figure out where the flash was. (Again, everything appears correct. Double-checked that it was set up the same as all others.) If you also watch the inspector window with the object selected, you can see the name of each animation frame as it goes by. So I did the frame-by-frame and saw that in two spots it said 'Sprite Missing'.

I figured they were just corrupted so I deleted them. But, the problem was still there (indicating that it wasn't an image issue.) Surprisingly though, when I tried dragging just those two images back in, everything worked fine. Who knows why ‍♂️

Anyway, mine at least was a simple fixed once I kind of figured out where the issue was at. so, hopefully this might help someone else out at some point.